# JAVA: How can I restrict a class to be extended on one level

Tags: java, design-patterns, inheritance

My problem statement is at below:

I am creating a library in java, for certain classes I would like the users should be able to extend my class but only at one level, those subclasses should not be available for sub-classing. It can be achieve if programmer their subclasses as final, but the decision would go to them. I want to control this from my library. how can I do this ?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I dont think you can put such a restriction. What is the scenario? where are you using it.

Comment: Why can the subclassing only go down one level?

Comment: This is not a doable thing, but does it even make sense to want it?

Comment: You could probably achieve this with reflection. Wouldn't make it any less pointless though.

Comment: Not sure whether I understood the question. Once the user sub classes your class, that sub class is under the control of the user. He may allow to subclass or not, but you will not be able to restrict that in your library.

Comment: There is not such thing, Interesting why do you need this thing? Your situation does not make sense. If it made sense,  we would see this thing in java(at least with fake way like using reflections).

Answer (score 11):

I suppose you could implement something like this with reflection:

```
public abstract class ExtendOnce {
    public static class Subclass extends ExtendOnce {

    }

    public static class SubSubclass extends Subclass {

    }

    protected ExtendOnce() {
        if (!getClass().getSuperclass().equals(ExtendOnce.class)) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "You extended this class more than once!");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Subclass());
        System.out.println(new SubSubclass()); // throws exception
    }
}
```

However, the more important question you need to be asking yourself is *do you actually need this restriction?*

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [Java reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) and call [getModifiers()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getModifiers%28%29) to check and see if the class is final.

You might be able do this from your superclasses constructor. If not, you'll have to pick some method that's required to be called. If you detect that it's not final, you can throw an exception, exit the JVM, or whatever else you want to do to keep it from working.

I can't imagine a good reason to do this, however. As a user of your library I would be annoyed by this arbitrary restriction.

Also, a user of your library could always wrap your object in their own object, and extend it by composition instead of inheritance.

Comment: Thanks this may help. I know its pretty difficult not to expose your class but yes it will sure help upto an extent.

Answer (score -1):

This is simple.  Just write up license terms.

If your software is useful, then your requirement is unusual but not a deal breaker.  For example, I would rather accept your requirement than spend money.

If your software is useless, then your requirement is unusual but not a deal breaker.  No one would care.

Comment: How is this useful?  At best it make unsubstainable assumptions.

Comment: @MartinSpamer Why is it not sustainable? If the OP can detect license violations, he can sue the violaters.  If he can't detect license violations, then one wonders why worry so much about it.  It shouldn't surprise the user like a run-time reflection based technique would.

Comment: Were does he say he want to sue license violators ?  That is another faulty assumption.